# Random numbers from Win32 API?

Tags: winapi, modula-2

Working on a Win32 API GUI application in Modula-2 (ISO) and there does not appear to be a way to generate random numbers in the libraries.  Before I roll my own PRNG (for fun simulation purpose only, does not need to be cryptographically sound), is there a way to get a random number from Windows?

Comment: Modula-2  has a Rand lib: FROM Rand     IMPORT RANDOM;

Comment: There's [BCryptGenRandom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptgenrandom) that only needs a buffer to be filled when passed the `BCRYPT_USE_SYSTEM_PREFERRED_RNG` flag.

Comment: @MitchWheat That would be nice and easy, but there's no Rand lib that I can find in the ISO libraries.  Using XDS 2.60 currently, but also checked in ADW just to make sure.